# Select more than 1 items in Datagrid (binding with DataTable)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to select more than one row in a datagrid, which is bind to a DataTable. Selecting one item is possible but if I set `SelectionMode` to "Extended" and `SelectedItems` **s** there comes a mistake that there is no setter object to access.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "MultiSelect"-property isn`t avaible...only SelectionMode, and this is set to "Extended"...I think the problem is that DataTable is not from Type IEnumerable, but how can i solve this problem?